# How to declare a function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I wan to declare a new function, like it is written [here](http://sumations.net/i/doc/XEDEV/xedev_plsql013.htm). But there is an Syntax Error risen. My ecode:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    RANDOM_MAX_VALUE integer := 100;

    FUNCTION random_int (max integer) RETURN integer IS
    BEGIN
        return floor(random()*max+1)
    END random_int

BEGIN
    LOOP 
    ...random_int(RANDOM_MAX_VALUE)...
    END LOOP; 
END $$;
```

The Error is (translated from German):

```
Error:  Systax Error by »integer«
LINE 14:  FUNCTION random_int (max integer) RETURN integer IS
                   ^
CONTEXT:  Not valid typename: »random_int (max integer) RETURN integer IS
BEGIN
    return floor(random()*max+1)
END random_int
```

What is bad with my integer? I was trying different approaches gathered from the internet, but without success. And the console does not gives a decent explanation to the Problem at all.

Comment: Do not get confused, that link you are showing is for Oracle's  procedural language (PL/SQL) not Postgres'  (PL/pgSQL )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a misunderstanding: confusing Oracle PL/SQL with Postgres PL/pgSQL.

Comment: "FUNCTION random_int (max integer) RETURN integer" has to have "RETURNS integer" at the and. Don't mix up RETURN and RETURNS.